# Using COALESCE with different data types?

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion, coalesce

I have a query using `COALESCE(timestamp_type::date,charachter_varying)` which fails due to the mismatched data types:

ERROR: COALESCE types date and character varying cannot be matched

It works if i cast the timestamp as `text`:

`COALESCE(timestamp_type::text,charachter_varying)`

However, now it is returning the full timestamp when I only want `YYYY-MM-DD` (instead of the full timestamp, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000000+00`)

**How can I use COALESCE *and* return only the date portion of the timestamp?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use to_char to convert the timestamp using appropriate format mask:

```
COALESCE(to_char(timestamp_type, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), varchar_col)
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct casting would be

```
COALESCE(timestamp_type::date::text,char_var)
```

This should work as you expect ... if you have the ISO datestyle. But it's MUCH better to not rely on datestyle settings for converting date-times to/from text. Hence, @Gurwinder Singh's answer is the way to go.