# How do I use COALESCE to return 'N/A' when the value of a TIMESTAMP column is NULL?

Tags: postgresql, coalesce, sql-timestamp, sql-null

Is it possible to use COALESCE (or any other way) to replace NULL values from a TIMESTAMP column with a string like 'N/A'?

In my `SELECT` statement I have a

```
CASE WHEN n.expiration_date::date IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE n.expiration_date::date END
```

When I try this, I get this error, which makes sense:

> invalid input syntax for type date: "N/A"

I found [this blog post](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/nhaam0y8qh-postgres-coalesce-errors-with-multiple-types) too about this problem. Is there a way around it?

Comment: If you use this in application, you might replace the `NULL`s there when showing the result.

Comment: You could also just do it with COALESCE: `COALESCE(n.expiration_date::date::text, 'N/A')`

Comment: @404 That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All values of a CASE expression have to evaluate to the same data type.

If you really need the N/A, you need to convert the date to a character type:

```
CASE 
    WHEN n.expiration_date IS NULL THEN 'N/A' 
    ELSE n.expiration_date::date::text 
END
```

Or if you want to have control over the format:

```
CASE 
    WHEN n.expiration_date IS NULL THEN 'N/A' 
    ELSE to_char(n.expiration_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
END
```

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks!
Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899262/using-coalesce-with-different-data-types